# Converting blob data into CSV file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore, blob

I am trying to convert blob data from ms-sql to csv file using python. Blob data itself has many other commas in it and that does not let me convert it properly.

Is there a way to escape commas in blob, but properly upload it to another db when needed.

I am doing this for a GAE project and downloading tables from a ms-sql db to upload GAE datastore. Since it supports xml as well, should I start using it?

--Update--

Converted sql row, which holds pdf file looks like this:

```
ObjectID,FileData,Extension,
2846748,"%PDF-1.3
%
3 0 obj
<<
/Producer (PDF-XChange 3.60.0102 \(Windows\))
/Author (HA)
/Creator (ABBYY PDF Transformer 2.0)
/CreationDate (D:20130612093531+02'00')
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 150
/Height 112
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/Length 3682
/Filter [/DCTDecode]
>>
stream
ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC



%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(ÿÛC...goes and goes on...", .PDF
```

In first try uploading this to datastore I got null char error and then removed them using

```
temp = str(rows[i][j]).replace("\x00", "")
```

Then I added quote marks as @Greg offered

```
if "," in temp:
    temp = "\"" + temp + "\""
```

After this changes I tried to upload it to data store and got **string is longer than 500 char error**. I had **export_transform: transform.blob_to_file('Filename', 'AttachmentBlobs')** line in bulkloader.yaml for FileData attribute, but it was seen as string.

And I discovered blob data should be uploaded to GAE blob datastore, I am not doing these transactions form a html form, but form python scripts, so now going to work on uploading that data to blob datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if a CSV field has commas in it, the field would be enclosed in "s. The python [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) package deals with such things, so if you're just splitting strings on ",", then switching to a csv.reader would probably work.

Otherwise, I think you need to edit your question to include an example of your input and the code you have that's not doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Adding quote marks solved comma issue, but now what should I do about other quote marks in the blob?